Яндекс карты. Получить данные объекта внутри кластера при клике
На карте вывожу много меток, которые объединяются в кластеры. Так же, есть форма, в поля которых должны попадать значения объекта, кликнутого на карте.

Так вот, если кликнуть по одиночному маркеру, то проблем нет, это я сделал, но проблема в том, что мне нужно чтобы поля формы заполнялись и при клике на объекте внутри любого кластера (когда кликаешь на кластер, там список из объектов) -

А я не пойму как получить клик по этим объектам и данные из них
Вот мой код карты


ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [56.841542, 60.571872],
        zoom: 4,
        controls: []
    }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        clusterize: true,
        clusterDisableClickZoom: true
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    objectManager.objects.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
        // Получим объект, на котором открылся балун.
        var id = e.get('objectId'),
            geoObject = objectManager.objects.getById(id);
        // Загрузим данные для объекта при необходимости.
        downloadContent([geoObject], id);
        let cityId = objectManager.objects.getById(id).properties.cityId;
        let shopId = objectManager.objects.getById(id).properties.shopId;
        let shopText = objectManager.objects.getById(id).properties.shopName;
        $('#contacts_form .js-cities-select').val(cityId).trigger('change');
        initShopsSelect($('#contacts_form .js-shops-select'), shopId, shopText);
    });
    objectManager.clusters.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
        // Получим id кластера, на котором открылся балун.
        var id = e.get('objectId'),
        // Получим геообъекты внутри кластера.
            cluster = objectManager.clusters.getById(id),
            geoObjects = cluster.properties.geoObjects;
            console.log(geoObjects)
        // Загрузим данные для объектов при необходимости.
        downloadContent(geoObjects, id, true);
    });


    function downloadContent(geoObjects, id, isCluster) {
        // Создадим массив меток, для которых данные ещё не загружены.
        var array = geoObjects.filter(function (geoObject) {
                    return geoObject.properties.balloonContent === 'идет загрузка...' ||
                        geoObject.properties.balloonContent === 'Not found';
                }),
        // Формируем массив идентификаторов, который будет передан серверу.
            ids = array.map(function (geoObject) {
                    return geoObject.id;
                });
        if (ids.length) {
            // Запрос к серверу.
            // Сервер обработает массив идентификаторов и на его основе
            // вернет JSON-объект, содержащий текст балуна для
            // заданных меток.
            ymaps.vow.resolve($.ajax({
                    url: '/local/ajax/map_balloons_json.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: false
                })).then(function (data) {
                        // Имитируем задержку от сервера.
                        return ymaps.vow.delay(data, 1000);
                }).then(
                    function (data) {
                        geoObjects.forEach(function (geoObject) {
                            // Содержимое балуна берем из данных, полученных от сервера.
                            // Сервер возвращает массив объектов вида:
                            // [ {"balloonContent": "Содержимое балуна"}, ...]
                            geoObject.properties.balloonContent = data[geoObject.id].balloonContent;   
    });
             // Оповещаем балун, что нужно применить новые данные.
            setNewData();
            }, function () {
                geoObjects.forEach(function (geoObject) {
                    geoObject.properties.balloonContent = 'Not found';
                });
                // Оповещаем балун, что нужно применить новые данные.
                setNewData();
            }
        );
    }

        function setNewData(){
            if (isCluster && objectManager.clusters.balloon.isOpen(id)) {
                objectManager.clusters.balloon.setData(objectManager.clusters.balloon.getData());
            } else if (objectManager.objects.balloon.isOpen(id)) {
                objectManager.objects.balloon.setData(objectManager.objects.balloon.getData());
            }
        }
    }
   
    $.ajax({
        url: "/local/ajax/map_data_json.php"
    }).done(function (data) {
        objectManager.add(data); 
    });

});



вот так выглядит массив объектов внутри кластера, когда кликнешь по нему


Проще всего привязаться к clusterCaption. Обёртываешь его в span,
geoObject.properties.clusterCaption= '<span class="cluster-caption" data-id="' + geoObject.id + '">' + data[geoObject.id].clusterCaption+'</span>'

а затем вешаешь обработчик клика по этому span,
$('body').on('click','.cluster-caption', (e) => {
   ...
});

берёшь его id, - а дальше элементарно. И даже не нужно будет привязываться к событиям балуна.

Спасибо за ответ, но что то не работает. Эту строку - geoObject.properties.clusterCaption= '' + data[geoObject.id].clusterCaption+'' - я помещаю внутрь oobjectManager.clusters.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {,  правильно же ?

Нет. в функцию с комментом // Содержимое балуна берем из данных, полученных от сервера.

а да, отлично, в span оборачивает, только clusterCaption отдает undefined почему то(

Ну, надо смотреть, где у тебя задаётся заголовок для балуна кластеризатора, и оборачивать там.

Большое спасибо за помощь!

Прикладываю пример получения значений объекта из кластера:
var monitor;
var g;
clusterer.events.group().add('balloonopen', e => {
if (monitor) {
monitor.removeAll();
monitor = undefined;
}
var cluster = e.get('cluster');
console.log('activeObject', cluster.state.get('activeObject'))
monitor = new ymaps.Monitor(cluster.state)
  .add('activeObject', () => {
    console.log('activeObject', cluster.state.get('activeObject'))
  });

})
В примере используются поля state и balloonopen.
